# Is it possible to get the frequency of currently active wi-fi connection on IOS with Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Because 2,4 ghz and 5ghz wi-fi connections can have same ssid's,and our device which I am trying to connect to is working only with 2,4 ghz band,I need to verify the current wi-fi connections frequency of the smartphone on which our xamarin.forms app is installed. Can't get anything related to it.This was quite straightforward with Android:

```
var mainWifi = (WifiManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
            if (mainWifi.ConnectionInfo.Frequency.ToString().StartsWith("24")){
//..do something
}
```

If anyone has any thougts how this can be done in iOS,would be welcome...

Comment: Not available to user apps in iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do this using publicly available APIs, as of iOS 7. The OS algorithm controls networking and decides which channel to use based on congestion, interference, and other factors.

If you're okay with using private APIs, then you can use Stumbler, a library that exposes the data you're interested in: https://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Stumbler

> **Warning:** If you want to use private APIs, then you won't be able to distribute through the App Store (and you'll have all the other
>   hazards that come with using Apple's private API: the banhammer,
>   breakage at any time, et cetera).

Comment: I read that NEHotspotNetwork entitlement could help me maybe.But diving into the classes it offers,I still don't see anything that would help me there.Maybe you know if this would help or not?https://developer.apple.com/documentation/networkextension